# inline display for divs in small screens bootstrap 5

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

How can we make two div that their display in small screens be block . and in large screens be inline !?
also I want to their width be 100% of the screen

Comment: [Bootstrap display class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/display/) & the [breakpoint](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/breakpoints/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably do something like this :

```
<div class="w-100 d-block d-md-inline">My first div</div>
<div class="w-100 d-block d-md-inline">My second div</div>
```

But you have to know that you can't define a size to an inline element. I think you would like to use "inline-block" instead of "inline".

Comment: no need of `d-block` as you set it into a `div` element. But it is a general example as we don't know they will apply